# emacs regexp replace C function call

Tags: c, regex, emacs

I'm trying to regexp match a C function, e.g.

```c
func(blah blah);
```

The match can include newlines.

I've tried:

```lisp
func([.+]);
```

which didn't do newlines, and:

```lisp
func([...]);
func([^...]);
```

neither of which seemed to do anything. I guess I'm looking for the part of a regexp that will match *any number/type* of characters between my opening `func(` and `);`.

Comment: What if the arguments include parentheses as well?  e.g. `func(x*(y+z))`.

Comment: they don't so not an issue in this instance

Comment: possibly emacs has something 'built-in' to comment/uncomment C function calls bypassing the need for an explicit regexp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `func[[:space:]]*([^)]*)`. Nested parens in calls will confuse it though.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the general case is not feasible with regular expressions, because the nested function calls are not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: thankfully its not a general case - just good enough to work across my own files (where I know I've not nested any parentheses)

Answer (score 1):

While Maxim's answer is specific, I'm going to guess you are looking to do something with the matched function you found.  To do serious code processing, you can't beat the semantic parser that is a part of CEDET's suite of tools.  http://cedet.sf.net is also part of Emacs.

If you use the semantic parser in emacs, you can:

```
M-x semantic-mode RET
```

and then in code:

```
(semantic-fetch-tags)
```

or

```
(semantic-current-tag)
```

to get the current tag.  Once you have the tag, you can call:

```
(semantic-tag-function-arguments mytag)
```

to get the arguments, which are tags.  For one of those, use `semantic-tag-name` to get the name, or `semantic-tag-type` to get the data type.

Once you've got your tag data, you can always write out new code with SRecode, which is a code generator which will take in tags, and spit out code, such as function declarations.